# I want there to be a message printed when all the values are either 0 or 1

Tags: python

the message "all heads" is printed every time 0 appears whilst the message "all tails" doesn't appear at all
what should happen is when every value is 0 "all heads" gets printed but if all the values are 1 the message "all tails"

i tried writing that if all a equals 0 an n amount of time the message will print but if a equals 1 an n amount of times a different message will be printed
the code

```
import random
n = int(input("enter the number of coin flips "))
a = []
for q in range(n):
a = (random.randint(0,1))
  print(a)
  if a == 0*n:
     print("all heads")
     if a ==1*n:
        print("all tails")
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it uses [images in place of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: NO IMAGE ! Please read the SO guidelines before posting

Comment: my bad i will make an edit

Comment: Please use code instead of image. You can copy your code and your results and post them.

Comment: `a = [random.randint(0,1) for _ in range(q)]` and then use the `all` function to figure out whether all match whatever condition you want - or `sum` a and check if it is 0 or n.

Answer (score 1):

You were overwriting your list and nesting conditions that need not be nested. Here is an implementation for your consideration.

```py
import random


def flip(n: int) -> list[int]:
    return [random.randint(0, 1) for _ in range(n)]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    flips = flip(int(input("how many? ")))
    print(flips)
    if all(f == 0 for f in flips):
        print("all 0")
    if all(f == 1 for f in flips):
        print("all 1")
```

Answer (score 0):

With `a = random.randint(0, 1)` you are overwriting your list.
Use this:

```
coin_flip = random.randint(0, 1)
a.append(coin_flip)
print(coin_flip)
```